# Glassfish Applications Not Starting

Tags: primefaces, glassfish-3

I was just reading about using libraries in glassfish. That is, put jar files in a 'centralized' location so that it can be accessed from different web applications. *domains-dir/lib/ext* is one of such locations. I put some jar files there and restarted the server. The restart was successful but no application would load; not even the admin console. I investigated this and found the culprit to be the primefaces jar file I put. On removing it, glassfish worked properly. I've tried versions 3.1 and 3.2 of primefaces and the results are the same. On checking the server log, I find that, with primefaces in the ext folder, the class `javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextFactory` fails to load. Any idea what might be causing this. I should probably try the other library locations like *domains-dir/lib/* but I'm curious.
By the way, I'm working on a windows 7 OS and using glassfish 3.1.1
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the libs in `domains-dir/lib/`.

From the Glassfish manual:

> To use the Common class loader, copy the JAR files into the domain-dir/lib or as-install/lib
>   directory or copy the .class files (and other needed files, such as .properties files) into the
>   domain-dir/lib/classes directory, then restart the server.
>   Using the Common class loader makes an application or module accessible to all applications
>   or modules deployed on servers that share the same configuration.However, this accessibility
>   does not extend to application clients.

More information about classloading in Glassfish can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sivakumart/entry/classloaders_in_glassfish_an_attempt).